# SQLAlchemy multithreading without flesk

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I want to access a sqlite database file from the main thread and a background thread. The problem is no matter how i change my code i always get the following problem:

```
ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.The object was created in thread id -1250925472 and this is thread id -1225814016
```

my code looks something like that:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///data/storage.sqlite', poolclass=NullPool)
Footprint.Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Session = scoped_session(session_factory)

def storeData(fp):
    s = Session()
    s.add(fp)
    s.commit()
```

Has anybody an idea how to fix this annoying problem?

Comment: SQLite is a small file-oriented database. This kind of database is not well suited for sharing a connection between threads because they require a global lock for writing, which is prone to all sort of concurrency problemas (like deadlocks and race conditions). II don't have time to write a proper answer right now (may be I can do it later if nobody else answer).

Comment: Thanks. The thing is i don´t want to install a full blown sql server. It is just a raspberry and i want to store maybe 100-200 records.